# Sysadmin change tracking/control app that's LAMP-based, free, wonderful?

Tags: lamp

I'm looking for a change tracking app.  It needs to be LAMP-based and free (as in beer).

I'm specifically looking for something for sysadmins.  Sysadmin makes a change on a server and logs a note of it in this web-based app.  Two days later someone complains something isn't working and another sysadmin can pull up a list of all changes to a server/app/etc.

I'm NOT looking for a bug tracking or defect-tracking or project management app...unless one of those is easily customized to what I'm asking for.

Change control is not vital...at the moment, I'm interested in tracking changes among a small group of admins, not implementing ITIL :-)

I don't need any sophisticated alerts integrations, etc. - just a simple log that people can write to.

Maybe there's something designed for this, or something generic that could easily serve?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [wiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki). We use it here as a CMDB/FAQ/Knowledge Base of sorts.

You can also put the changed area under version control system like SVN and log the changes, but that is kind of strange (but I know people who do).

Or you can use a configuration management system like puppet or chef and use SVN or GIT to keep track of the changes on configuration, but this is going the other way around of what you want.

Comment: +1 on a Wiki.  Also consider something like RANCID for automatically pulling and archiving network device setup.

Comment: Yes, a wiki is possible.  All right, I'll consider that - thank you.  What else is there?

Comment: @raindog The other part of the answer is another good option to consider; a config management tool plus version control gives you a great means to answer the "what changed?" question, with no extra documentation work required by the admins (even the best of us will forget to write something down sometimes).